# Como deletar arquivos de uma pasta recursivamente baseado numa expressão?

Tags: cmd, powershell

Estou utilizando um projeto onde existe vários arquivos temporários que, por algum motivo, não foram deletados ao longo do tempo e que estão ocupando muito espaço.

Preciso deletar todas as imagens desse determinado diretório, recursivamente, quando esses arquivos comecarem com as letras "LX".

Como posso fazer isso usando o PowerShell ou o CMD?

Por exemplo, na estrutura abaixo, cada uma das subpastas possuem esses arquivos iniciados por "LX".

```
DIRETORIO
    FOTOS_1
       1.jpg
       2.jpg
       LXa45axdgg.jpg
    FOTOS_2
       1.jpg
       2.jpg
       LXa4bbbbxdgg.jpg
    FOTOS_3
       1.jpg
       2.jpg
       LXa4555g.jpg
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usando o Powershell é fácil.

```
get-childitem . -include LX*.* -recurse | foreach ($_) {remove-item $_.fullname}
```

O comando [`Get-Children`](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/ee176841.aspx) retorna uma coleção de arquivos.

- O ponto (`.`) representa o local de partida (a pasta onde o *script* está rodando).
- O `-include LX*.*`, serve para "dizer" ao comando para retornar apenas os arquivos que satisfaçam esta condição.
  Você pode adicionar mais condições separando-as por vírgula: **`-include LX*.*, lx*.*`**.
- O `recurse` faz o comando ser recursivo. Ou seja, olhar dentro das pastas filhas da pasta atual e dentro das filhas das filhas e assim por diante.

Depois de `Get-Children` é feito um *foreach* que passa por todos os elementos da coleção e chama o comando **`remove-item`** para deletá-lo.

Answer (score 7):

Utilizando o `cmd`, você pode fazer os seguinte:

```
del /s *.{sua extensão}
```

ou caso deseje pelo nome do arquivo, pode fazer o seguinte:

```
del /s LX*
```

Lembrando que para isso você deve estar no "diretório raiz", ou seja, em **DIRETORIO**.

Caso queira uma confirmação antes de excluir cada arquivo, utilize a opção `/p`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Del/f/s/q LX*.*
```

`/f` = força exclusão de arquivos somente leitura

`/s` = inclui TODOS os subdiretórios, ou seja, excluirá **TODOS** os arquivos iniciados em `LX` de todos os diretórios a partir do qual você executar o comando.

`/q` = não pede confirmação. Se desejar confirmar, um por um, use `/p`.

Lembre-se que utilizando o `/s`, o comando excluirá de **TODAS** as pastas, então, certifique-se de que realmente pode excluir **TODOS** esses arquivos.